Friends play practical joke/prank on him, and it goes wrong
Friends play prank on a boy like this: they send a girl to him and then the girl pretends that she dies, maybe she pretends she has a heart-attack or something.
The boy and his friends go to somewhere to dig a grave for the dead girl (who is actually alive). While digging the grave, the boy gets very upset and he hits the girl's body with something heavy and the girl is now really dead.
Somebody (maybe a stranger) stalks on the boy and his friends while they are digging the grave and eventually the stranger takes revenge from the boy's friends by killing them one by one.
A friend of mine told this movie plot but he couldn't remember the movie name. I wonder if anybody knows what it is.

This is Sorority Row.


Sorority Row is a 2009 American slasher film directed by Stewart Hendler and starring Briana Evigan, Leah Pipes, Rumer Willis, and Carrie Fisher. Based on the script for the 1983 horror film The House on Sorority Row by Mark Rosman and Bobby Fine, the film is a re-imagining that focuses on a group of sorority sisters who are stalked and murdered on the night of their graduation after covering up the accidental death of a fellow sorority sister.

....

After finding out that her boyfriend Garrett (Matt O'Leary) has cheated on her, Theta Pi sorority sister Megan (Audrina Patridge) enlists the help of her friends and fellow sorority sisters Cassidy (Briana Evigan), Jessica (Leah Pipes), Ellie (Rumer Willis), Claire (Jamie Chung), and Garrett's sister Chugs (Margo Harshman) to pull a prank on him. After Megan fakes her own death while having sex with him, Garrett and the girls bring her to a lake, where they intend to dump her body. When Jessica mentions they need to release the air out of her lungs so her body will not float to the surface, Garrett stabs Megan in the chest with a tire iron, killing her for real. Realizing what they've done, the group dump Megan's body and the tire iron in a nearby mine shaft. Everyone swears to never mention the incident to anyone, much to Cassidy and Ellie's dismay.

